# Remmina connection issue to Windows Server 2012R2 after Windows Update

Tags: server, windows, remmina

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and Remmina to connect to a Windows Server 2012R2 computer. I am being prompted for my password and put it in successfully, but fail to login to the server. I was able to connect prior to a set of Windows updates. What can I do to resolve the issue and connect to the server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is the certificate was changed on the server as a result of the update, but Remmina did not prompt to update the certificate. Navigate to the .freerdp folder and edit known_hosts file. The entry for the target machine needs to be removed. Upon the next connection attempt you will be prompted to accept the new certificate and will be able to connect to the server after accepting the certificate.

Comment: I also had to re-create the entry in remmina

Answer (score 1):

Run 'remmina' from commandline to watch output and deduce the root cause.

I was able to solve by:

1. Deleting my windows self-signed certificate and rebooting so that it would re-create a new one. (mmc.exe>file>add snap-in>certificates>computer account>local computer then Certificates>Remote Desktop>certificates: delete the existing cert)
2. Then remove the known certificate for remmina/xfreerdp:

- purge or modify ~/.config/freerdp/known_hosts2
- purge or modify ~/.freerdp/known_hosts
- (depending on remmina/distribution versions)